# Which regexp is faster

Tags: pcre

I am using PCRE`|^/foo/(.*?)(?::(?:bar)?)?$|` or `|^/foo/(.*?)(?::bar)?:?$|` this will be a replace so we want to strip `:` and `:bar` from the end while doing the replacement. I know the two are not exactly the same but it does not matter much here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first one as it only has to check for `:` once. The second one could match the first three characters of `:bat` before having to backtrack, then check for `:` again. Also, the second one could match `:bar:` whereas the first one can't. The actual speed difference would be tiny. The second way would be better written as `/^\/foo\/(.*?)(?::bar|:)?$/`

Try not to use regex metacharacters as delimiters!